# Mutliple Regression Calibration Curve

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-transformation, calibration

Background:
I am using an instrument that measures two physical properties, X1~Temperture and X2~ Velocity. When gathering the data to make the curve a set of predetermined concentrations are chosen from the desired range, usually 1% to 25%. The temperature is varied in a control manner consistent across all concentrations. Each chemical has a different shape, some include inflection points in the data. This is a scatter plot of the raw data:

[image: Example of one Chemical of which the concentration is being tested]

I would like to perform regression analysis in R.

Questions: 
1.) Is it valid to split the data into a training and validation set? 
`train.size <- 0.8
train.index <- sample.int(length(Conc), round(length(Conc)*train.size))
train.sample <- MYdata[train.index,]
valid.sample <- MYdata[-train.index,]`

2.) Is there a standard way to approach this data that could be applied to multiple different chemicals? Example: nonlinear least squares, using the "NLS" function, or a way to estimate a polynomial or logarithmic transformation. I am not getting good data using NLS. The code I'm using is:

```
 NLS <- nls(Conc ~ b*Temp + c*SV, start=list(b= -1.3, c= -1.3))
```

3.) Would fractional polynomial be a good choice to try for this? I am unsure how to perform this, but it did seem promising.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the background of the data? How they were collected, what the R code looks like? Etc.

Comment: Sure thing. The data is collected one concentration at a time. So 1% concentration would be put in the instrument and X1=temperture which is changed at a determined rate, X2=the instrument read out of m/s. After various concentrations are tested, they need to combined to make a calibration curve to be used in the field. LM <- lm(Conc ~ X1+X2, data=data)
summary(LM)


NLS <- nls(Conc ~ b*X1 + c*X2, start=list(b= -.3, c= -.3))
summary(NLS)